# Usb automount in linux box

Tags: linux, usb, automount

When a usbdisk is connected to a linux box, A folder with usb label is created in /media and mounted. how is it done & how it works in backend. can anyone please explain.

Thanks
Caterpillar.

Comment: Google is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

udev is the key. Have a look at the files under /etc/udev/rules.d

- [udev Howto](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)
- [Create your own udev rules](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=168221)